# How to remove individual markers in Google maps api3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates, google-maps-markers

I know there are other solutions out there but none of them apply to my situation that easily because my markers are in a function and a marker is created from an external XML file where if you change the coordinates you add a marker in that current position. here is my code for the markers

```
var lastCoordinates={};
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({map:map})
var path = [];
function gotdata(){

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){

        var d = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement 
            //innerHTML shouldn't work for XML-Nodes
            y = d.getElementsByTagName("y")[0].textContent,
            x = d.getElementsByTagName("x")[0].textContent,
            h = [x,y].join('_');
        if(lastCoordinates[h]){
          return;
        } 

        lastCoordinates[h]= new google.maps.Marker({
                              position: new google.maps.LatLng(x,y),
                              map: map,
                              title: 'YAY'
                            });
         path.push(lastCoordinates[h].getPosition());
         if (path.length >= 2) {
           // display the polyline once it has more than one point
           polyline.setMap(map);
           polyline.setPath(path);
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  How to remove a marker knowing its coordinates?  If not from it's coordinates (and that seems obvious from your code) how do you identify the one you want to remove?  Or do you want to remove the markers's "point" from the polyline as welll?

Comment: the marker i would like to remove would be chosen by using preferably a right click but i would like for the poly line to remain if that's possible

Comment: What did you try?  If you have the coordinates it should be straightforward to remove the marker.  There is no 'rightclick' handler in your code.

Comment: if the right click is not available how would i remove the marker using coordinates while leaving the polyline there

Answer (score 0):

```
function gotdata() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
    count++;
    // var d = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement 
    //innerHTML shouldn't work for XML-Nodes
    y = count * 0.01; // d.getElementsByTagName("y")[0].textContent,
    x = count * 0.01; //d.getElementsByTagName("x")[0].textContent,
    h = [x, y].join('_');
    if (lastCoordinates[h]) {
        return;
    }

    lastCoordinates[h] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
        map: map,
        title: 'YAY'
    });
    rightclickableMarker(lastCoordinates[h],h);    
    map.panTo(lastCoordinates[h].getPosition());
    path.push(lastCoordinates[h].getPosition());
    if (path.length >= 2) {
        // display the polyline once it has more than one point
        polyline.setMap(map);
        polyline.setPath(path);
    }
  }
}
function rightclickableMarker(marker, h) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(evt) {
        if(lastCoordinates[h] && lastCoordinates[h].setMap){
          lastCoordinates[h].setMap(null);
          delete marker;
        } 
    });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6955Losb/3/)

Comment: if i place that where is says 'function gotdata' no marker appears and the console says get data is not defined

Comment: Does the fiddle work for you? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue **in your question itself**.